# Less/CSS : get value of this property

Tags: css, this, less, addition

I would like to achieve the following in less :

```
.bar {
    width: 100px;
}

.foo .bar {
    width: this + 20px // 120px
}
```

Is this possible with Less and if so, how ?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible. Why aren't you just adding a margin to `.bar`?

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't this work?

```
@width: 100px;

.bar {
    width: @width
}

.foo .bar {
    width: @width + 20px
}
```

Comment: Yes in theory but in my case the width of .bar will be variable and calculated by a combination of outside variables. (its in fact the Bootstrap .container which is calculated with a bunch of less variables).